# How to code to display three image buttons with single class?

Tags: css

I suppose to complete one task. The main objective of the task is to display image buttons with padding differencde 10px.

here it is my html output:

```
<div width="100%" style =" float:right"  >
    <input type="image" value="resources/images/btn-tabl.png"  class ="tabl_btn"/>
    <input type="image" value="resources/images/btn-map.png" class ="tabl_btn"/>
     <input type="image" value="resources/images/btn-graph.png" class ="tabl_btn"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabl_btn {
    width: 62px;
    height: 28px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Buttons are displaying with  padding but when i click padding space also showing.
[image: Image buttons are displaying but when i click it's displaying including padding space]

How can i display only button?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: JSF and PrimeFaces is in this regard just an html generator. Look at that in your browser developer tool and check what css should be applied. Learn css, good (your class in the css totally does not match the styleClass in the xhtml and there is totally no PrimeFaces relation here...

Comment: First try to replace `.btnbutton` by the class you are using in the html, ie `.tabl_btn`

Comment: Indeed. You will have more chance in answers from CSS experts if you start off with HTML code which CSS actually works on. Rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser to find it and normalize it for the question. Once you get the answer from CSS experts, it's a matter of rewriting server side code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML output.

Comment: the space or the outline? Then again, check what css is applied that causes this and change that... All just basic html and css.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are really asking is how you can eliminate the focus outline that shows up in Chrome and Firefox. This is done by applying the following code:

```
input[type="image"]:focus,
input[type="image"]:active {
color: red;
outline: none;
```

}

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/un401mzv/1/).